# Shopeware 6 unable to add product with APIs

Tags: php, api, shopware

I am working with shopeware 6 and adding the data with APIs. Using their documentation i have implemented the APIs for adding categories. Because they have given it in the docs. For more API info they asked to open swagger link.

So i tried it. But in the swagger there is no proper explanation of APIs. Somehow i manage to implement manufacturer API. But Now not able to implement add product APIs.

Please help me and let me know the required fields for the add product apis. I have tried API with some data but got error.

> URL- https://www.meptrade.co.uk/api/v1/product Type - POST    {
>     "stock":1000,   "taxId":"f6ac5dsvjbd7wd3b2i32bb89e2e802fc1a1e",
>     "price":"100",  "name":"test",
>     "manufacturerId":"72f26544ddfbb55eb3bwbt348ec0ea717" }

**Error:-**

> {"errors":[{"code":"c1051bb4-d103-4f74-8988-acbcafc7fdc3","status":"400","detail":"This
>   value should not be blank.","template":"This value should not be
>   blank.","meta":{"parameters":{"{{ value
>   }}":"null"}},"source":{"pointer":"/0/productNumber"}}]}

Comment: A bit late to the party.  But the product payload looks different.  Below is an example how we successfully create products:
        {
            'name': 'Product Name',
            'stock': 292,
            'taxId': 'tax_id_from_api',
            'productNumber': 'some-product-sku',
            'active': True,
            'price': {
                'currencyId': 'currency_id_from_shopware',
                'gross': 121.0,
                'net': 100.0,
                'linked': True 
            }
        }

Comment: As there doesn't seem to be any documentation, you can use the debug-mode to find out how shopware6 makes it's calls. 
- in file .env set your mode to dev
- in the backend, there is a debug-toolbar on the right bottom.  Click it.
- change a product, and look at the api-calls in the debug-toolbar
This helped a lot to figure out how to use the shopware6 api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says you are missing a required field, which in this case is the `productNumber`. A product needs several required fields. You can look them up in the [ProductDefinition](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.1/src/Core/Content/Product/ProductDefinition.php#L101) (they have the `Required` flag)
You need at least:

- name
- manufacturer
- productNumber
- tax
- price
- stock

You could also have a look at the [product api test](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.1/src/Core/Content/Test/Product/Api/ProductApiTest.php) which creates a product in its tests.

Comment: In my case, when using the _action/sync API to import the product's delivery-times and stock (write-product => [ 'entity' => 'product', 'action' => 'upsert', 'payload' => [id = .., deliveryTimeId = .., stock = ..]])  I get four errors like the one above during import, specifically for:  "price", "productNumber", "translations\/2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b\/name", "taxId". Do I really need to add these to the request? I don't want to change anything related to price or tax ID..